# Number of balls covering a $n$-dimensional sphere

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

What upper bounds for number of covering a unit sphere balls with a same radius $r$ and centers on this sphere are known?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a reference. Have a look at [Lemma 3 in Section 1.4.3 "Maximising Over the Euclidean Ball"](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~qb204/teaching/set_1.pdf). (The numbering is poorly done; Lemma 3 is at the end of page 10.) That gives (almost) exactly what you want. (It's a lecture course I'm doing at the moment.)

This gives the proof that it's the number of balls of size $r$ required to cover *the whole ball* is less than or equal to $(3/r)^n$. Note, however, the stark difference in high-dimensional geometry: for large $n$, the volume concentrated around the boundary is where almost all the volume of the ball is. Indeed, suppose you have constants chosen such that the volume is $r^n$. Then $(\frac{r}{0.99r})^n \to \infty$ and $r^n - (0.99r)^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you provide a link for your reference?

Comment: Certainly, I have just done so. Apologies, I hadn't noticed that I'd forgotten the link!

Comment: In fact, the dimension of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ being $n-1$, you can achieve a covering with $(A/r)^{n-1}$ balls of radius $r$ for a constant $A$. See Geller and Pensenson, Band-Limited Localized Parseval Frames and Besov Spaces on Compact Homogeneous Manifolds, Theorem 4.5. [Link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12220-010-9150-3)

Comment: This comment is worthy of an answer in of itself! :) -- although I must confess I don't see how one uses the aforementioned Theorem 4.5 to deduce your claim. Also, please use the open-access [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3841) rather than a paywall(?) journal :)